# Trying to import SwiftyJSON.framework

Tags: ios, import

I am trying to include SwiftyJSON as found here:

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#initialization

I installed Carthage with homebrew and setup a Cartfile as described on the [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) github page under the **If you're building for iOS** heading.

I have the following directory structure:

```
x/
x/Cartfile
x/Cartfile.resolved
x/Carthage/Build/iOS/SwiftyJSON.framework
x/MyProject/{my Swift code and project}
x/MyProject.xcodeproj
x/MyProjectTests
```

Here's my project's **General -> Linked Frameworks** section:

[image]

Here's my project's **Build Phases -> Run Script** section:

[image]

If I don't have any code that references `JSON` then I'm fine. I can build. I can even get the dummy response from my little server providing some json stubbing.

However, as soon as I add let `json = JSON(data: swiftObject)` I'm in trouble.

No matter what I seem to do I get the following:

[image]

I *know* I must be missing something obvious or completely silly but I'm at my wits end. I haven't been able to find anyone explaining this issue via Google (Or I'm just having a bad day for searching). Can anyone point me toward what I'm probably overlooking or just totally missing?

Comment: Welcome @Kevek. Your question looks great though consider posting similar questions to StackOverflow in the future since your question is programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to import the framework in the swift file where you try to use JSON().

import SwiftyJSON

Comment: Welp, I don't know why I thought that was unnecessary. Could swear I read it. Thanks.